# Single quotes not being replaced in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to sanitize quotes from a text input. Right now my code is:

```
string = string.replace(/'/g, '\'');
string = string.replace(/"/g, '\"');
```

My out put has all double quotes replaced, but the single quotes remain. I am fairly confident in my regex, and haven't had a problem with the replace function before. Is there a chance that mySQLdb is messing this up? I am posting it and then getting almost immediately after. This seems like such a simple issue but it really has me stumped

Comment: There is a chance that what you assume is an `apostrophe`, really is a `grave accent` or even a left|right `single quotation mark`. Take look to this https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your replacements are null operations since the backslash is consumed by the string literal itself and is not present in the actual string value.

Instead escape the backslash to really get one in your string:

```
string = string.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
string = string.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

You can of course do this in one operation:

```
string = string.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1");
```

Comment: oh wow duh! I should have seen this duh. Thanks so much. Question, what is the replacement string \\$1?

Comment: The `$1` is a backreference to what ever was matched in the capture group in the regular expresion (denoted with parentheses). So it will be the quote, whichever one it was. The ``\\`` is the escaped backslash, so a literal backslash.

Comment: it did! apologies, I was unable to select an answer and it completely slipped my mind to come back and do it